# How input my own File Name for "Saved capture image as file"?

Tags: irfanview

1. Is there Instruction Manual or Beginner Guide to how pick "File name" style?
2. Like what does $ mean?
3. % mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How you pick a filename depends on you and you alone. You will have to decide how to structure the names. From the image on the OP, the names of the saved files will start with `capture_` followed by numbers then the current date time. If you don't like them to start with `capture_` and prefer maybe `Image`, you can replace it. You must experiment to avoid some of your images to have the same name if you remove the numbers and/or the date and time.

`$U` means current system date/time. From Irfan's view [Text/Patterns Options](http://irfanview.helpmax.net/en/options-menu/textpattern-options/):

> ```
> Placeholder Tag name/function
>
>
> $D -        file directory/folder (whole path)
> $d  -        file directory/folder (last subfolder only)
> $F  -        file name (with extension)
> $N  -        file name (without extension)
> $O  -        file extension
> $S  -        file size
> $T  -        file date/time (see Appendix A for additional examples)
> $U  -        current system date/time (see Appendix A for additional examples)
> $X  -        file directory index
> $M  -        page index in a multipage image
> $Z  -        actual zoom size (for full screen/slideshow)
> $W  -        image width
> $H  -        image height
> $B  -        image bits per pixel
> $p  -        image DPI
> $C  -        JPG/Webshots image comment, if available
> $I  -        all IPTC data
> $Ix -        value of the JPG IPTC tag x, if available (x is a number, see below) (IPTC PlugIn required)
> $E  -        all EXIF data
> $Ex -        value of the JPG EXIF tag x, if available (x is a number, see below) (EXIF PlugIn required)
> |   -        new line
> ```

For date and time:

> ```
> %Y  -        year, 4 numbers
> %y  -        year, 2 numbers (00-99)
> %m  -        month
> %d  -        day
> %H  -        hour
> %M  -        minute
> %S  -        second
> ```

There are more patterns listed on the same page.